# Kubuntu not installing properly

Tags: boot, nvidia, kubuntu, alienware

As the title says I'm having a problem installing Kubuntu. I'm trying to run Kubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my Alienware laptop. Before putting it on that I installed it on my old Asus and encountered no problems. The issue I am having is after it installs and prompts a restart once I click the button to restart the text box disappears but the laptop never restarts. I can manually turn the laptop off and back on but from there it will not load properly unless I launch it in recovery mode. When I try and launch it normally everything works fine until I input my password and the computer freezes up. I did not have this issue when running it on my old Asus laptop despite using the exact same image and USB stick. I thought perhaps it would be a graphics issue but the Alienware uses a slightly newer NVIDIA chip than the old one and both load the same driver at install, so I'm at a loss for what to do.

**EDIT** My laptop doesn't have a Software & updates thing, it just has a driver manager. When I try and click on the recommended (middle) option instead of allowing the driver to change like it used to it just refreshes and doesn't apply the change.
[Driver Manager as it's loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqNJZ.png)

[Driver Manager once it's loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEjXF.png)

Comment: you might have to add the nomodeset option to your boot option until you get the new drivers installed... posting answer now

Answer (score 0):

**Set nomodeset option and run updates**

Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) and set the nomodeset so you can boot.

Once you are booted add the nvidia driver ppa and run updates:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now reboot and see that everything works. If so, you can go to `Software & Updates -> Aditional Drivers` and install the recommended nvidia driver.

Now reboot and remove the nomodeset option and see if it will boot. If not, just add it back.

Comment: Every time I try and apply the change to the driver, the driver manager just refreshes without ever applying the change, is there any way around this?

Comment: you mean in software & updates? can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshots, they came out as links, sorry, I'm still getting used to how the site functions.